# Order rows based on aggregated data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table like shown below :

```
select * from sampleTable;
 label | data 
-------+------
 a     |    1
 b     |    2
 c     |    3
 d     |    4
 a     |    5
 b     |    6
(6 rows)
```

I require rows to be sorted with the summed up values of 'data' column (i.e) c with data of 3 should come first and b with combined data of 2 and 6 should come last and others in-between like shown below

```
 label | data 
-------+------
 c     |    3
 d     |    4
 a     |    1
 a     |    5
 b     |    2
 b     |    6
```

I have tried to achieve this with a self join as shown below.  But it seems a bit verbose.  Am I doing it right or is there a better way to achieve the same without joins?

```
select l, data from sampleTable join (select label as l, sum(data) as x from sampleTable group by l) m on label = m.l order by x;
 l | data 
---+------
 c |    3
 d |    4
 a |    1
 a |    5
 b |    2
 b |    6
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the self-join by using a `SUM` with a [windowed function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), something like this:

```
SELECT label
    , data
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , SUM(data) OVER (PARTITION BY label) pts
    FROM sampleTable
    ) AS rez
ORDER BY pts
```

Comment: Better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a self-join or a subquery.  You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by sum(data over (partition by label),
         label;
```

Note the inclusion of `label` as the second key.  This is important for distinguishing ties in the data.  It ensures that the all rows for a given label all appear together.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the sum window function in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT l, d
FROM tab
ORDER BY SUM(d) OVER (PARTITION BY l)
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c45016711b646866052c4f5d19bf454a)